# Navbar list-element doesn't go active when clicking or scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, navbar

I have been trying to figure out this annoying problem. I have tried to have my navbar list elements go active while scrolling through the site or clicking the elements(they should change color or whatever). Css does come through when I "force" the list-element active. So when I inspect element the li-element I have clicked doesn't go "active".
So for example it should show:

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="#toiminta">Assistenttimme</a>
</li>
```

, but instead it shows it:

```
<li>
  <a href="#toiminta">Assistenttimme</a>
</li>
```

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
<li class="hidden">
<a href="#page-top"></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#toiminta">Assistenttimme</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#about">Prosessimme</a>
</li>


<li>
<a href="#pricing">Ratkaisut & Hinnat</a>
</li>


<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Lisää<span class="caret"></span>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">


<li>
    <a href={% url "work" %}>My</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href={% url "faq" %}>F.A.Q.</a>
</li>

</ul>
</li>
</ul>


</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->

</nav>
```

Here is the code for javascript(I don't know much about this):

```
// Scrollspy: Highlights the navigation menu items while scrolling.
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
});
```

Any ideas why the list-elements don't turn active?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin appears to need a specific target for managing the effect, and in your snippet you use "navbar-fixed-top". That class isn't in your HTML anywhere - perhaps you meant to use "navbar-collapse"?